# Restrictive ACL for Trading network in Hyperledger Composer

Tags: acl, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I couldn't solve my problem, so i try to explain it again:
There are 2 Participants (Provider). Both of them holds own Wallet and Account and they want to exchange Cash to Tokens or visa versa. They should have just READ-access to their own assets, because of fraud, security etc. But for transactions they need UPDATE-access. Here is my code:

org.acme.biznet.cto:

```
namespace org.acme.biznet

abstract participant Member identified by memberId {
o String memberId
o String name
o String email
}
// Sensorbesitzer, z.B private Personen, Haushalte etc.
participant Provider identified by providerId extends Member {
o String providerId
--> SDTWallet sdtWallet
--> Account account
}
// SDT Token Wallet von den Netzwerkteilnehmern.
asset SDTWallet identified by sdtWalletId {
o String sdtWalletId
o Double balance default = 0.0 
--> Member owner 
}
// Geldkonto von den Netzwerkteilnehmern.
asset Account identified by accountId {
o String accountId
o Double balance default = 0.0
--> Member owner 
}
// Cash gegen Tokens getauscht.
transaction TradeCashToTokens {
o Double cashRate default = 2.0
o Double cashValue default = 1.0 range = [1.0,]
--> SDTWallet fromSDT 
--> SDTWallet toSDT
--> Account fromCash
--> Account toCash
}
// Tokens gegen Cash getauscht.
transaction TradeTokensToCash {
o Double tokenRate default = 0.5       
o Double tokenValue default = 2.0 range = [2.0,]    
--> SDTWallet fromSDT
--> SDTWallet toSDT
--> Account fromCash
--> Account toCash
}
```

and logic.js:

```
/**
* Cash to tokens transaction
* @param {org.acme.biznet.TradeCashToTokens} UpdateValues
 * @transaction
*/
function TradeCashToTokens(UpdateValues) {

//determine change in tokens value from the rate
var tokensChange = (UpdateValues.cashRate * UpdateValues.cashValue);

if(UpdateValues.fromCash.balance < UpdateValues.cashValue) {
    throw new Error('Insufficient cash funds!');
} else if (tokensChange > UpdateValues.fromSDT.balance) {
    throw new Error('Not enough tokens for this transaction!'); 
}
//alert("Fehler!");

//update values of exchanger1 cash account
console.log('#### exchanger1 cash balance before: ' + UpdateValues.fromCash.balance);
UpdateValues.fromCash.balance -= UpdateValues.cashValue;
console.log('#### exchanger1 cash balance after: ' + UpdateValues.fromCash.balance);
//update values of exchanger2 cash account
console.log('#### exchanger2 cash balance before: ' + UpdateValues.toCash.balance);
UpdateValues.toCash.balance += UpdateValues.cashValue;
console.log('#### exchanger2 cash balance after: ' + UpdateValues.toCash.balance);
//update values of exchanger1 token wallet
console.log('#### exchanger1 token balance before: ' + UpdateValues.toSDT.balance);
UpdateValues.toSDT.balance += tokensChange;
console.log('#### exchanger1 token balance after: ' + UpdateValues.toSDT.balance);
//update values of exchanger2 token wallet
console.log('#### exchanger2 token balance before: ' + UpdateValues.fromSDT.balance);
UpdateValues.fromSDT.balance -= tokensChange;
console.log('#### exchanger2 token balance after: ' + UpdateValues.fromSDT.balance);

console.log(UpdateValues.cashValue + ' EUR exchanged to ' + tokensChange + ' SDT Tokens with actual rate of ' + UpdateValues.cashRate);

return getAssetRegistry('org.acme.biznet.SDTWallet')
    .then(function (assetRegistry) {
        return assetRegistry.updateAll([UpdateValues.toSDT,UpdateValues.fromSDT]);
    })                
    .then(function () {
        return  getAssetRegistry('org.acme.biznet.Account')
        .then(function (assetRegistry) {
            return assetRegistry.updateAll([UpdateValues.toCash,UpdateValues.fromCash]); 
        });            
    });     
}
```

and permissions.acl:

```
//****************PROVIDER_PARTICIPANTS**********************

//Provider has access only to their own profile
rule ProviderAccessOwnProfile {
description: "Allow providers to access only their profile"
participant(p): "org.acme.biznet.Provider"
operation: READ, UPDATE
resource(r): "org.acme.biznet.Provider"
condition: (r.getIdentifier() === p.getIdentifier())
action: ALLOW
}

//Provider has read only access to other Providers
rule ProviderReadAccessProviders {
description: "Allow provider read access to other providers"
participant: "org.acme.biznet.Provider"
operation: READ
resource: "org.acme.biznet.Provider"
action: ALLOW
}

//****************PROVIDER_ASSETS**********************

rule ProvidersReadAccesstoAccount {
description: "Traders see their own BankAccount only"
participant: "org.acme.biznet.Provider"
operation: READ
resource: "org.acme.biznet.Account"
action: ALLOW
}

rule ProvidersReadAccesstoSDTWallet {
description: "Providers see their own SDT Wallet only"
participant: "org.acme.biznet.Provider"
operation: READ
resource: "org.acme.biznet.SDTWallet"
action: ALLOW
}

//Provider can submit CashToToken transaction
rule ProvidercanUpdateAccountthroughTransactionOnly {
        description: "Allow trader to submit trade transactions"
        participant(p): "org.acme.biznet.Provider"
        operation: READ, UPDATE
        resource(r): "org.acme.biznet.Account"
        transaction(tx): "org.acme.biznet.TradeCashToTokens"
        condition: (p.getIdentifier() === r.owner.getIdentifier() && 
r.getIdentifier() === tx.toCash.getIdentifier())
        action: ALLOW
}

//Provider can submit CashToToken transaction
rule ProvidercanUpdateSDTWalletthroughTransactionOnly {
        description: "Allow trader to submit trade transactions"
        participant(p): "org.acme.biznet.Provider"
        operation: READ, UPDATE
        resource(r): "org.acme.biznet.SDTWallet"
        transaction(tx): "org.acme.biznet.TradeCashToTokens"
        condition: (p.getIdentifier() === r.owner.getIdentifier() && 
 r.getIdentifier() === tx.fromSDT.getIdentifier())
        action: ALLOW
 }


//****************PROVIDER_TRANSACTIONS**********************

//Provider can submit CashToTokens transaction
rule ProviderSubmitCashToTokenTransactions {
description: "Allow provider to submit cash to tokens transactions"
participant: "org.acme.biznet.Provider"
operation: CREATE, READ
resource: "org.acme.biznet.TradeCashToTokens"
action: ALLOW
}

//Provider can submit TokenToCash transaction
rule ProviderSubmitTokensToCashTransactions {
description: "Allow provider to submit tokens to cash transactions"
participant: "org.acme.biznet.Provider"
operation: CREATE, READ
resource: "org.acme.biznet.TradeTokensToCash"
action: ALLOW
}

//****************PROVIDER_HISTORY**********************

//Provider can see the history of own transactions only
rule ProviderSeeOwnHistoryOnly {
description: "Proviers should be able to see the history of their own 
transactions only"
participant(p): "org.acme.biznet.Provider"
operation: READ
resource(r): "org.hyperledger.composer.system.HistorianRecord"
condition: (r.participantInvoking.getIdentifier() != p.getIdentifier())
action: DENY
}

//*********************NETWORK***************************
rule SystemACL {
description:  "System ACL to permit all access"
participant: "org.hyperledger.composer.system.Participant"
operation: ALL
resource: "org.hyperledger.composer.system.**"
action: ALLOW
}

rule NetworkAdminUser {
description: "Grant business network administrators full access to user 
resources"
participant: "org.hyperledger.composer.system.NetworkAdmin"
operation: ALL
resource: "**"
action: ALLOW
}

rule NetworkAdminSystem {
description: "Grant business network administrators full access to system 
resources"
participant: "org.hyperledger.composer.system.NetworkAdmin"
operation: ALL
resource: "org.hyperledger.composer.system.**"
action: ALLOW
}
```

And when i want to try make transactions as Provider, e.g. TradeCachToTokens, it says `t: Participant 'org.acme.biznet.Provider#P1' does not have 'UPDATE' access to resource 'org.acme.biznet.SDTWallet#SDT1'`

please see the screenshot: [cash_to_tokens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rz47Z.png)

Provider(P1) should get UPDATE-access for Wallet and Account, if he make transaction, but not only his own, for his opposite (P2) too.

Whats the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

UPDATED ANSWER: the answer is (May 10):

1. You are updating the registries `org.acme.biznet.SDTWallet` and `org.acme.bixnet.Account` - and I see you have rules to allow updates to occur from the transaction `TradeCashToTokens` or indeed `TradeTokensToCash`. I think the problem is the condition should be || and not && - one resource at a time is evaluated, and the resource owner can be TRUE in the conditional match. As the trxn is invoked by the participant, should always evaluate TRUE (unless he's not the resource owner of course), part A of the condition  ; for the target resource (`toCash` or `toSDT`), you compare it with the owner of the resource (being updated in your transaction function code - names as above). Note the rules are based allowing the invoking participant update the 2 target resources (based on participant, not Account - ps I think the reason your 'SDT' rule failed is because the rule says 'fromSDT' (evaluates to one target resource only).

   Suggest a set of rules like:

   ```
   rule UpdateAccountsviaTradeCashToTokens {
       description: "Allow source/target providers defined in trxn (ie 2)- to access/update their Accounts from, trxn TradeCashToTokens only"
       participant(p): "org.acme.biznet.Provider"
       operation: READ, UPDATE
       resource(r): "org.acme.biznet.Account"
       transaction(tx): "org.acme.biznet.TradeCashToTokens"
       condition: ( p.getIdentifier() === r.owner.getIdentifier() || tx.toCash.owner.getIdentifier()  === r.owner.getIdentifier() )
       action: ALLOW
   }


   rule UpdateSDTWalletsviaTradeCashToTokens {
       description: "Allow source/target providers defined in trxn (ie 2)- to access/update their SDT Wallets from, trxn TradeCashToTokens only"
       participant(p): "org.acme.biznet.Provider"
       operation: READ, UPDATE
       resource(r): "org.acme.biznet.SDTWallet"
       transaction(tx): "org.acme.biznet.TradeCashToTokens"
       condition: ( p.getIdentifier() === r.owner.getIdentifier() || tx.toSDT.owner.getIdentifier()  === r.owner.getIdentifier() ) 
       action: ALLOW
   }
   ```
2. Similarly - for the other transaction `TradeTokenstoCash` you can have

   ```
   rule UpdateAccountsviaTradeTokensToCash {
       description: "Allow source/target providers defined in trxn (ie 2)- to access/update their Accounts from, trxn TradeTokensToCash only"
       participant(p): "org.acme.biznet.Provider"
       operation: READ, UPDATE
       resource(r): "org.acme.biznet.Account"
       transaction(tx): "org.acme.biznet.TradeTokensToCash"
       condition: ( p.getIdentifier() === r.owner.getIdentifier() || tx.toCash.owner.getIdentifier()  === r.owner.getIdentifier() )
       action: ALLOW
   }

   rule UpdateSDTWalletsviaTradeTokenstoCash {
       description: "Allow source/target providers defined in trxn (ie 2)- to access/update their SDT Wallets from, trxn TradeTokenstoCash only"
       participant(p): "org.acme.biznet.Provider"
       operation: READ, UPDATE
       resource(r): "org.acme.biznet.SDTWallet"
       transaction(tx): "org.acme.biznet.TradeTokenstoCash"
       condition: ( p.getIdentifier() === r.owner.getIdentifier() ||  tx.toSDT.owner.getIdentifier()  === r.owner.getIdentifier() )
       action: ALLOW
   }
   ```
3. You will still need your `PROVIDER_TRANSACTIONS` rules.
4. You are correct to say you will need the `PROVIDER_ASSETS` rules - before the transaction update based rules (ie mentioned above).
5. I have created an ACL tutorial - that I will incorporate into the Composer docs in due course (for benefit of others too)  - similar to what you've done.

https://github.com/mahoney1/test/blob/master/acl_dynamic.md

Hope this helps, have tried your complete ruleset with changes and it works; if you wish me to post the complete set of rules, let me know.

Comment: I don't know, that I expressed myself good enough. I'm not native english speaker, but I try again: There are 2 Traders and they have own wallets and accounts-Assets. They should get just READ-Access to their own assets, because Wallet and Account should have some sort of balance-Variable and don't want, that they change this Variable on their own. Balance should just get changed by transactions. For transactions we have Coin and Cash-Assets, but the result of this transactions affects the wallet and account-Assets, so I have to give them Traders UPDATE-Access on wallet and account-Asset,which

Comment: is actually bad. so how should the ACL for the traders be? Or is my idea logical wrong? I mean, if i have a network, some sort of exchange for example, the members should'nt have UPDATE-Access on their Wallet and Account-assets. It gets updated just by transactions: for example CashToCoin. So i need 2 additional assets: Cash and Coin. The traders should be able do transactions on their own with each other. This transactions affetcs Cash and Coin-assets, so the traders have to UPDATE-Access for this assets. But what should i do with Wallet and Account-assets?They get also updated

Comment: Your defined transaction, will only perform the updates . A transaction is initiated by one participant  - but the 2 traders will need to have access to update  their target assets affected. Part of that is to update (say) a balance on the account - via the same transaction. So the 'UPDATE' will be 'marshalled' by a transaction - it being an integral part of the ACL rule - which is why I have put the `transaction (tx)` as a part of my ACL rule. Outside of that transaction(tx), those 'traders' cannot update their assets independently. Does that help?

Comment: some participant has to sign a transaction - whether that's the traders or another participant designated to perform the transactions. That's the whole point of a permissioned blockchain - you can see who performed what - tied back to a blockchain identity.  As I mentioned, traders cannot perform an update to the ledger outside of the approved/automated transaction method.

Comment: please check this again! @Paul O'Mahony

Comment: hi there - my answer above - is added to specify the ACL rules that should match (or be similar to) what you want from the model/ACLs posted and in the context of your main question above :-)

Comment: So I have tested your suggestion and now I have really strange problem: If I try to submit a transaction for example TradeCashToTokens. As soon as I click submit-button my notebook get higher CPU load and it thinks and thinks, you know this circle icon instead of arrow icon. And at the end all freezes and i have to close my Chrome Browser. See this screenshot: [Browser freezes](https://imgur.com/a/hXCHbHb). So i can give you my BNA-file, if you want to try, what I meant.

Comment: yes, please send as attachment in S/O mail etc else on Rocketchat by DM if you wish - would be easier.

Comment: I provided you my BNA-file with this use case on Rocketchat.

Comment: hi there, eventually got to test your rules, it is working and I've updated my answer (post-comments earlier).